# combining Zuhr and Asr in work

Tags: salat, practical-islam

I'm working in Australia and it's hard to do ablution due to improper place at work. Also to avoid -ive comments can I combine zuhr and asr in my work place in a non-muslim country

Comment: No, wiping over socks is recommended in cases like yours to ease ablution. Wiping over socks is valid for 5 prayers or something like that for a resident, if you wear cotton/nylon socks after ablution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, perform you Zhur prayer about ten minutes before beginning of Asr time  once the time of Asr comes do your Asr

Comment: that's what I figured out